# How to use swapbuffers in Graphics.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, bgi, double-buffering, winbgi

So atm im using swapbuffers in this code to refresh it:

```
    #include "graphics.h"

void drawGridOnX(int xtotal, int ytotal);
int levelcode[400][45][100];
void decodelevelAndDraw();

void main() {
    initwindow(1600, 900,"Testscreen",0,0,true,true);
    int gridposx = 0, gridposy = 0, diffx = 0, diffy = 0, xtotal=0, ytotal = 0,distanceFromMouse=50;


    while (1) {
        setbkcolor(9);
        ytotal = 0;
        diffx = mousex() - gridposx;
        while (gridposx < mousex()&&diffx>=70) {
            gridposx += 70;

        }
        while (gridposx > mousex()&&diffx<=-70 + distanceFromMouse) {
            gridposx =gridposx-70;

        }
        diffy = mousey() - gridposy;
        while (gridposy < mousey() && diffy >= 70) {
            gridposy += 70;

        }
        while (gridposy > mousey() && diffy <= -70+distanceFromMouse) {
            gridposy = gridposy - 70;

        }
        while (ytotal < 900) {
            drawGridOnX(xtotal, ytotal);
            ytotal += 70;
        }
        if (WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
            levelcode[gridposx/70][gridposy/70][0]=1;
            printf("CLICK");
        }
        decodelevelAndDraw();
        readimagefile("question.bmp", gridposx,gridposy, 70+gridposx, 70+gridposy);
        printf("gridposx:%d\tgridposy:%d\ttitlenumberx:%d\ttitlenumbery%d",gridposx,gridposy,gridposx/70,gridposy/70);
        swapbuffers();
        cleardevice();
    }
}


void drawGridOnX(int xtotal, int ytotal) {
    while (xtotal < 1600) {
        rectangle(xtotal, ytotal, 70 + xtotal, 70+ytotal);
        xtotal += 70;

    }


}


void decodelevelAndDraw() {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    while (y != 12) {
        while (x != 22) {
            if (levelcode[x][y][1] == 1) {
                readimagefile("question.bmp", x*70, y*70, 70 + x*70, 70 + y*70);

            }
            x++;
        }
        y++;
    }

}
```

So im using it at the end of the drawing procedure followed by a clear device.
That kinda works exept when playing animations or drawing something in the backround ( that gets deleted ). I dont understand how i should use it. I know its used for double buffering and its supposed to swap out the pregenerated next frame with the old one but everywhere i looked its explained poorly. 
How can i use swapbuffers effectively so that i can play animations and draw stuff in the backround ( like my programm is supposed to do when the player left clicks ) without it dissapearing?

Im using the librarys from this site http://winbgim.codecutter.org/

Comment: It could help people help you if you would provide a reference to the library you're using that provides `<graphics.h>`.

Comment: Are you using WinBGIm?

Comment: I includet my librarys in the post

Comment: Your question has the `visual-studio-2015` tag but the link you gave seems to mention only MinGW. Which compiler are you using? Are you using the MinGW compiler with Visual Studio as your IDE?

Comment: No. They work just fine in visual studio. I had to do a few tricks to get the .a library to work. Just google it. Its been some time and i cant remember how i did it :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what libraries you're using, but from the names of the functions you are calling, it looks like you're clearing the color buffer right after swapping the back buffer with the front buffer. I don't think that will work. Also, I'll further assume that the `setbkcolor` function sets the color that will be used to clear the color buffer. The way I'm used to doing real-time graphics is like this:

```
repeat {
    // check for and handle user input
    // set background color
    // clear color buffer
    // update scene information
    // render the new scene
    // swap the buffers
}
```

However, in your code, you seem to clear the color buffer right after swapping, your loop should look like this (the changes have been marked with comments):

```
while (1) {
    setbkcolor(9);
    cleardevice(); // line of code added
    ytotal = 0;
    diffx = mousex() - gridposx;
    while (gridposx < mousex()&&diffx>=70) {
        gridposx += 70;

    }
    while (gridposx > mousex()&&diffx<=-70 + distanceFromMouse) {
        gridposx =gridposx-70;

    }
    diffy = mousey() - gridposy;
    while (gridposy < mousey() && diffy >= 70) {
        gridposy += 70;

    }
    while (gridposy > mousey() && diffy <= -70+distanceFromMouse) {
        gridposy = gridposy - 70;

    }
    while (ytotal < 900) {
        drawGridOnX(xtotal, ytotal);
        ytotal += 70;
    }
    if (WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        levelcode[gridposx/70][gridposy/70][0]=1;
        printf("CLICK");
    }
    decodelevelAndDraw();
    readimagefile("question.bmp", gridposx,gridposy, 70+gridposx, 70+gridposy);
    printf("gridposx:%d\tgridposy:%d\ttitlenumberx:%d\ttitlenumbery%d",gridposx,gridposy,gridposx/70,gridposy/70);
    swapbuffers();
    // cleardevice(); // line of code removed
}
```

Edit: I forgot to explain the changes. The way you were doing it, every time a frame was rendered and shown to the user, it would be immediately erased by the `cleardevice` call. By moving the `cleardevice` call to the beginning of the loop, you clear the old frame before rendering and showing the new one. I must confess though that this is mostly guesswork on my part because I don't know which libraries you're using.

Comment: I includet the librays in my post

Comment: Also this actually doesnt change anything because im still having the same problems as before! Can you maybe check the librays im using and see if you can come up with a different answer? While you are doing that im gonna run some tests to see if its actually working and im just too stoopid