# Double Buffering with graphics.h

Tags: c, buffer

Can you do double buffering in C using graphics.h, if not, is there any other ways?

i tried the tutorials on youtube, they are using graphics.h, but it wont work on mine since ssthread is needed and i believe it is only in c++, I'am just a student wanting to learn programming so i rely on tutorials online

Comment: graphics.h is really an old thing, probbaly older than you. I wouldn't invest too much time into these antique technonolgies. But anyway, maybe you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286830/how-to-use-swapbuffers-in-graphics-h

Comment: If you are looking for a version of BGI which will work with Visual Studio: https://github.com/nirin/WinBGI